# Problem with access to string from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, nsstring

Hi i have two view controller: FirstViewController and SecondViewController

```
FirstViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController: {
 NSString *prStr;
  } 

 -(IBAction)setString;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *prStr;

 @end
```

---

```
 FirstViewController.m

 #import"FirstViewController.h"

 @implementation FirstViewController

 @synthesize prStr;

 -(IBAction)setString{
  prStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"1"];

   }
```

---

```
 SecondViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FirstViewController;

@interface SecondViewController: {
 FirstViewController *pr;
  } 

 -(IBAction)example;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) FirstViewController *pr;

 @end
```

---

```
 SecondViewController.m

 #import"SecondViewController.h"
 #import "FirstViewController.h"

 @implementation SecondViewController

 @synthesize pr;

 -(IBAction)example{
  NSLog(pr.prStr);
  if([pr.prStr isEqualToString:@"1"]==YES){

     //Do Something            }

   }
```

When i build and run app, at execution of IBAction example, on debugger console doesn't appear anything!! How can access to the string of FirstViewController from action of SecondViewController, in order to display it on the debugger console???

Comment: Problem solved, i declared a NSString in appdelegate and i use it as a global variable: i set the string in first view controller and i read it in second viewcontroller using appDelegate.prStr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that you haven't alloced it.
Even if you alloc that, you should alloc as a singleton object.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you never actually call setString, so the value is not actually set.

Except from that, i think it is just not good practive to use a propertie's getter directly as an IBAction (even though IBAction is equivalent to void)

Answer (score 0):

U allocate the memory for that object(pr) and try it out.