# Hot to pass Values between views or classes?

Tags: iphone

i have a view with label when button pressed moves to second view controller with a picker view , i need to retrive the selected value and then to pass to first view's label,

i have used delegates and protocols to acheive this,

but is there any possible  ways like referencing like etc to do this?

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279310/problem-with-access-to-string-from-another-class/4279619#4279619

Answer (score 1):

You can use a singleton class to store the selected data and then can retrieve it wherever you want. Just like you get UIApplication's instance from 'sharedApplication' method, its the same object in the memory through out the application lifecycle.